# FeynCalc Notebook does not run

Tags: feyncalc

I've been trying to run an example of Chiral perturbation theory calculation. The notebook is from the site [here](http://www.feyncalc.org/phi/examples/ChPT/Pions+Baryons/PiN.nb.gz).
Every time I run the notebook, the InsertFields command throws up an error the says

```
loading generic model file $Failed
Get: $Failed is not a string, SocketObject, InputStream[], or OutputStream[].
$Aborted
```

Please help!

Comment: You might luck asking on the official FeynCalc forum: https://feyncalc.github.io/forum

Comment: Thanks! Will check one modification tomorrow (changing "Nucleon[0,j1]" to "Nucleon[0,{j1}]" etc). If it does not work out, will approach the forum.

Comment: Asked in the forum. Apparently, they've stopped supporting the package. "Unfortunately, the PHI extension is currently broken and unmaintained. The old examples required an extensive patching of FeynArts that is not feasible anymore. None of us is currently working in the field of ChPT, so I'm afraid that fixing PHI does not have a very high priority."